# Wrong class inheritance with self.__class__?

Tags: python, pylons, wtforms

I was working with inheritance in `WTForms`.
I had next class:

```
class MyForm(WTForms):
    ...
    def process(self, formdata=formdata, obj=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).process(formdata=formdata, obj=obj)
```

And I had error (not always, but in some cases with similar forms - it is even more strange):

`Maximum recursion depth have been exceeded`

But when I've changed `self.__class__` → `MyForm` everything was OK!

I don't get it... As I know they must be synonyms. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not synonyms. `self` may be any object of a class that *inherits from* `MyForm`. Python does not silently create a new superclass object for calling inherited methods, it just passes the same object (doing so would break polymorphism and serve no use). And the `type()`/`.__class__` is obviously the class the object is really an instance of, not some superclass of that (you don't expect `MyShinyThing().__class__` to yield `object`, right?). It would be really astonishing, non-idiomatic and useless if `__class__` changed depending on where it is accessed from. It's just polymorphism.

And as the first argument to `super` is an indicator where in the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) the search for a supermethod should continue (informally: where you currently are), passing `self.__class__` always starts back at the (immediate) superclass of whatever class `self` is an instance of. Assuming proper `super` calls elsewhere in the class hierarchy, this ultimately gets you back to `MyForm.process`, and we've got our infinite loop.